# changing the value of map with respect to particular key in java

Tags: java, dictionary

I have created a map which will ultimately drop a message to queue that is the message drop to the queue is of map type now but right now the map contain of the below key value pairs

```
 Map(<String , String >) rmap = new HashMap(<String , String >);
    rmap.put(ID, 750);
    rmap.put(FILELOC,"C:\\ta\\");
    rmap.put(FILENAMES,"wer.xls");
```

now the problem with the above map is that it is for a single file that is for wer.xls so lets say right now there are 4 different files shown below

```
abc.xls
ert.xlsx
gftr.xls
ewrt.xlsx
```

now i want that an loop to be called above map in which first two key values will remain same every time that is ID , FILELOC will remain same for all above 4 files but the last key FILENAMES value will be change with every seprate excelfile , one way to achieve is that i have created a list for the third property of map but i do not wish to do that , please advise how can i put a loop in map in which it first two properties will remain same

and the third key FILENAMES value will be changed some thing like this

```
rmap.put(FILENAMES,"abc.xls");
rmap.put(FILENAMES,"ert.xlsx");
rmap.put(FILENAMES,"gftr.xls");
rmap.put(FILENAMES,"ewrt.xlsx");
```

other way to achieve this is to create 4 different maps

```
Map(<String , String >) rmap1 = new HashMap(<String , String >);
    rmap1.put(ID, 750);
    rmap1.put(FILELOC,"C:\\ta\\");
    rmap1.put(FILENAMES,"abc.xls");


     Map(<String , String >) rmap2 = new HashMap(<String , String >);
    rmap2.put(ID, 750);
    rmap2.put(FILELOC,"C:\\ta\\");
    rmap2.put(FILENAMES,"ert.xlsx");


     Map(<String , String >) rmap3 = new HashMap(<String , String >);
    rmap3.put(ID, 750);
    rmap3.put(FILELOC,"C:\\ta\\");
    rmap3.put(FILENAMES,"gftr.xls");


     Map(<String , String >) rmap4 = new HashMap(<String , String >);
    rmap4.put(ID, 750);
    rmap4.put(FILELOC,"C:\\ta\\");
    rmap4.put(FILENAMES,"ewrt.xlsx");
```

is there any other way in which i can fit this in a loop and third key should be changed dynamically

Comment: Shouldn't this `Map(<String , String >) rmap` be written as `Map<String , String > rmap`, or am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

If you to keep the first two keys same and update only key "FILENAMES" with latest value then just do `rmap.put(FILENAMES,"latestFileName");` it will keep last updated value but if you want to keep all file names then make value as list of strings instead of just string and then add file name whenever you get new file

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a case where you should be using an object rather than a map. For instance:

```
class Entry {
    private String id;
    private String fileLocation;
    private List<String> filenames;

    Entry(String id, String fileLocation) {
        this.id = id;
        this.fileLocation = fileLocation;
    }

    public Entry addFilename(String filename) {
        filenames.add(filename);
    }

    // ...and getters and such as appropriate...
}
```

Then simply use an `Entry` instance instead of a `Map<String,String>` instance:

```
Entry entry = new Entry(750, "C:\\ta\\");
entry.addFilename("wer.xls");
entry.addFilename"ert.xlsx");
entry.addFilename"gftr.xls");
entry.addFilename"ewrt.xlsx");
```

(And if you have more than one of them, store in a list or map as appropriate.)

---

Re your comment about looping entries and looping their filenames: Suppose you have a list of `Entry` instances:

```
List<Entry> list = /*...create and fill in the entries...*/;
```

To loop through them, and list them and all of the filenames associated with them, you'd use a nested loop:

```
for (Entry entry : list) {
    System.out.println("ID: " + entry.getId());
    System.out.println("Location: " + entry.getFileLocation());
    for (String filename : entry.getFilenames()) {
        System.out.println("File: " + filename);
    }
}
```

Comment: then please explain lets say if i add iterate over map to print the entries of the map will i get 4 different entries in which first two key value will be same only the last key value will be different .

Comment: @tuntuntutufnmgjg: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're asking. If you're saying you'd have a map or list of `Entry` instances, and you're wondering how you'd get all the filenames when iterating, you'd do it by iterating the instances and, on each iteration, iterating the filenames.

Comment: Thanks can you also please show that it will be great help thanks in advance

Comment: @tuntuntutufnmgjg: I've added an example at the end.